# How to configure autozsys, so that it doesn't destroy zfs snapshots older than X time?

Tags: zfs

I think that autozsys destroys snapshots older than a month and I'm wondering if it's possible to extend this (make it for example persist 3 months worth of snapshots).

I couldn't find any configuration file for autozsys, only a cron job in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90_zsys_system_autosnapshot, but I hoped for more sophisticated means to control it.

Comment: I'm beginning to believe that users can't configure it that easily. [This](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/03/ubuntu-20-04s-zsys-adds-zfs-snapshots-to-package-management/#:~:text=according%20to%20age.-,The,-garbage%20collection%C2%A0ruleset) article mentions that zsys.conf exists, but it's editable only at the compile-time. I might have been wrong about the "garbage collection" though. It seems like zsys should only remove snapshots when there is 20% or less disk space left. Possibly these missing snapshots were deleted from my machines in some other way (oops)

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: thanks, I'm going to update to 21.10 in a moment, just want to sort out one thing with a broken plasma configuration. Hopefully, it's unrelated to the crux of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep absolutely all automatic snapshots from the last 3 months, ensure `gcStartAfter` is set to `90` in `/etc/zsys.conf`. At minimum, the file would look as follows:

```
history:
  gcstartafter: 90
```

Once the file is saved, effect the change via:

```
zsysctl service reload
```

Source: a blog post by the author of ZSys, which is linked to by the [ZSys GitHub repository](https://github.com/ubuntu/zsys) in lieu of proper documentation: https://didrocks.fr/2020/06/04/zfs-focus-on-ubuntu-20.04-lts-zsys-state-collection/

Comment: thanks, didn't even know that there can be zsys.conf

Comment: Happy to help - you can mark this answer as "accepted" if you feel this answers your question.

Comment: `/etc/zsys.conf` is missing in my config… should I create it to enable snapshot auto deletion on age?

Comment: I created mine based on the example from https://didrocks.fr/2020/06/04/zfs-focus-on-ubuntu-20.04-lts-zsys-state-collection/, but the file is also available at https://github.com/ubuntu/zsys/blob/dfe2f0482c69670683fa34a4a1525b1699b4460a/internal/config/zsys.conf

Answer (score 0):

Zsys removes snapshots based on free space left (min. 20% by default), not time like I initially thought. My snapshots must have disappeared in some other, unrelated way.

Also it seems like configuration of zsys is done only at compile-time as hinted at the end of [this article](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/03/ubuntu-20-04s-zsys-adds-zfs-snapshots-to-package-management/#:%7E:text=according%20to%20age.-,The,-garbage%20collection%C2%A0ruleset).

Comment: Where did you find that ZSys removes snapshots based on space left on the device?